# Identifying high NDVI values close to vector lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi, arcgis-10.6

I have NDVI raster data and vector line data for the St George Queensland [irrigation channels](https://data.qld.gov.au/dataset/sunwater-ltd-infrastructure-queensland-series/resource/4821b243-9d1f-495c-93cb-666622ab1d95).

I am trying to detect irrigation channel leakage using high NDVI values detected on the immediate bank.

How would I identify high NDVI values close to the channel lines in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Can you please refine your question into specific questions? What program are you using? What was your approach before asking here? These are very basic tasks that should be answered in most help pages of common software or tutorials and literature.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused Q&A model operates. Each question needs to include one task, with complete details of the software in use, steps taken, and problem encountered.

Comment: Good afternoon Luke,  I'll answer the easy part.  I have ERDAS Imagine 2015, ARCGIS 10.6 and QGIS 3.2.   I can also get IDRISI Selva if necessary.Irrigation Channel line data.  Not sure what you mean here but I have 3m pixel images of the St George Queensland irrigation area.  Neville Brisbane

Comment: I've made some edits that should allow your Q. to be reopened. Roll back if you disagree.  You can ask about exporting pixel coordinates in a separate Q. (or search, pretty sure it's been asked before)

Answer (score 1):

Potential solution for ArcGIS, assuming that you have the spatial analyst extension. You  will need to define two thresholds: one for the distance that you consider as "near" and one for the NDVI that you consider as "high".

1) Compute the Euclidian distance between to your lines. Make sure that the resolution is the same as your NDVI raster + use snapping in the environment so that the two layers nicely match each other.

2) With the raster calculator, identify areas of large NDVI (e.g. > 0.6) within a given distance (e.g < 10 m)

> Con( ( "distance" < 10 ) & ( "NDVI" > 0.6 ) , 1, 0 )

Comment: I would suggest Euclidian Distance rather than buffer + vector to raster. Mainly because it's easier to experiment with different distance thresholds.

Comment: good idea, I've updated my answer